# How to add static resources in spring with thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, static, resources, thymeleaf

I am new to **Spring** and I am trying to make a beautiful Web Application, and so far I set up everything, and if I run my page on the browser it shows as it is supposed. But if I run it with tomcat on port *8080* (I am using Intelijj) it doesn't load **css** and **js** files not even pictures.

I have literally searched this problem and open all the StackOverflow similar questions, I tried to write a configuration file, but it doesn't do anything, and I am uncertain about this approach because I have seen examples of people that did not write any configuration, but still they managed to make all their static resources load, and so on. Is it some secret application properties that need to write? Or there is a config code that has to write?

My resources folder looks like this:

```
-resources
    -static
        -CSS 
            -things.css
        -JS
            -datepicker.js
        -Images
            -many pictures
    -templates
        -Home.html and other pages
```

And the code that I used to refer to static-CSS-things.css is like this:

```
link href="../static/CSS/things.css" th:href="@{/CSS/things.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css"
```

I thought this would make my css file to load, but it doesn't. Same for the js and the pictures. Thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. Ensure your css and js files are in the following structure:

   src/main/resources/static/css/things.css

   src/main/resources/static/js/things.js
2. Ensure you are calling your static resources from pages that are under the spring boot template folder, which is in src/main/resources/templates
3. Always refer to your resources using the thymeleaf tag, because this way no matter the port you are running your application, it will always load properly.

**src/main/resources/templates/example.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link th:href="@{/css/things.css}" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    <!-- JS -->    
    <script th:src="@{/js/things.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

If still not working, try to use the inspect from Google Chrome, go to Network tab and check what error is returning from your css and js files, then comment here.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you have css and js folder under static folder then use it like this -

```
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

you might wanna take a look at these too -

https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-with-static-content-css-and-javascript-js
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources

Worth noting, make sure you have thymeleaf dependency(ies) and tags appropriately.

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem is that I followed those rules, but they don't seem to work. If I run the page on browser, it shows perfectly. If I run it with Tomcat, it shows awful. The back end works, at least. And I did use those tags, and the thymeleaf tags and so on. I just can't figure out what this bug is...

Comment: Thank you, but I've come to conclusion that writing bad code in your controller affects the static resources to load (I did some debug, because the html code and thyme leaf syntax are perfectly wrote). Now, they do load. But the controller doesn't do what I want :)))