# Bootstrap not loading when my html files are in templates folder

Tags: html, intellij-idea, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I am trying to do my very first own web app with Spring, Thymeleaf and everything seemed to be going well, however after I separated my html files in "templates" folder, since that is required to use thymeleaf, my bootstrap,JS,CSS and all my other resources stopped working.
I have my boostrap included with CDN with the css included in the header and JS,jQuery and popper included in the bottom of the body. I've tried moving the CDN links all in the header, removing my own js and css, however it didn't work.
You can review the html below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>EventFinder</title>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand">eventfinder</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">

            </span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page"  href="/">Organize an event</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page"  href="/">Register</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/login">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Logout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div id="slides" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="../static/images/music.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Music events">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="../static/images/arts.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Art events">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="../static/images/travel.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Travel and outdoor events">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="../static/images/hobbies.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Hobbies">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row welcome text-center">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1 class="display-4">Welcome to eventfinder.</h1>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="col-12">
            <p class="lead">Here you can search, join and create all kind of events. Eventfinder is free of charge web app, where people with the same
                interests can match and meet in real life.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row container-fluid padding">
        <div class="person_container col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="img-area">
                <img src="../static/images/person1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail person_pic">
            </div>
            <p>Some text here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="person_container col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="img-area">
                <img src="../static/images/person2.jpg" class="img-thumbnail person_pic">
            </div>
            <p>Some text here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="person_container col-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="img-area">
                <img src="../static/images/person3.jpg" class="img-thumbnail person_pic">
            </div>
            <p>Some text here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="my-4">
</div>

<div class="my-div-body">
    <div class="row container-fluid">
        <div class="col">
            Most recently added events
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row recently-added-container container-fluid">
        <div class="col">
            TO ADD EVENT HERE
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            TO ADD EVENT HERE
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            TO ADD EVENT HERE
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row welcome text-center">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1 class="display-4">Best cities to visit</h1>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="container-fluid padding">
            <div class="row padding">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="city-img-top" src=""/>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">City Name</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">Some text here</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">See more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="city-img-top" src=""/>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">City Name</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">Some text here</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">See more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="city-img-top" src=""/>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">City Name</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">Some text here</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">See more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../static/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also you can check my project structure here:

[image: project structure]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Open up the console. Does it say anything?

Comment: Hi, the console in intelliJ doesn't throw any errors, however the one in the browser throws 404 for my local files and that the resource is blocked due to MIME type mismatch, but only for them. Nothing for the bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to let thymeleaf handle paths for resources and not use relative ones.
For example set the folowing properties

```yaml
spring:
  web:
    resources:
      static-locations: classpath:/static/
      chain:
        strategy:
          content:
            enabled: true
            paths: /resources/**
```

and then in the html do
`<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/style.css}">` and
`<img th:src="@{/images/person3.jpg}" class="img-thumbnail person_pic">`

This way you do not have to add an arbitrary amount of `../` to paths

Comment: Hello, since I am using .yml file and not .properties I've added the following:

  web:
    resources:
      chain:
        strategy:
          content:
            enabled: true
            paths: resources
      static-locations: static

And also added the th: and the pathing references to my html, however this still didn't solve my issue and I still get those 404 errors in the console in the browser, also the bootstrap is still not working.

Comment: @Borislav edited reply to use (hopefully correct) yaml, But even without said properties standard /static folder files should've worked. 

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497306/how-to-add-static-resources-in-spring-with-thymeleaf for an identical question

Comment: Hi Ralan, after researching in the publication, which you send me i've successfully resolved the issue with the 404 errors in the browser console and I've also was successful in rendering the bootstrap! Thank you very much.