How to use import in JavaScript while using Spring Boot
I ve been looking for a way to use import Chart from 'chart.js/auto' in my webpage. Im currently using Spring Boot, with Thymeleaf.
Problem is, none of the things I tried worked. I have a node_modules inside my Static resources, and I cant seem to load the scripts from there.
If I try to just import my JS using
<script th:src="@{/js/graficaLoader.js}"></script> 
it just says
Cannot use import statement outside a module
If I import using type=module, then
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "chart.js/auto". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
I cant really store all my scripts inside the own html, I need separate files for doing things and its driving me mad.
I tried looking for this exact thing and I can however find info about it. I just started Web Development after being focused on Java for around a year.

Does this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497306/how-to-add-static-resources-in-spring-with-thymeleaf or you can use public folder to put your css or js stuff. Then you use them like this - <script th:src="@{/js/mycustom.js}"></script>

@AjayKumar Problem is, if I use some imports inside my JS, it just fails dont know why. I can seem to import modules from js into my js files

I finally figured it out. Turns out I wasn’t fully aware of how to use Spring and static resources, not only that, also Modules.
<script type="importmap">

    {
        "imports": {
            "chart.js": "/node_modules/chart.js/auto/auto.js",
            "@kurkle/color": "/node_modules/@kurkle/color/dist/color.esm.js"
        }
    }

</script>
<script type="module">
    import 'chart.js';
    import '@kurkle/color';
</script>

First of all I had to use an import map to import my resources from /node_modules/, served in static resources.
Then I had to call my JS that uses the import as a module:
<script type="module" th:src="@{/js/graficaLoader.js}"></script>

Finally, use import inside it:
import Chart from 'chart.js';

